# Handling activity views touches on top of fragment with scrollable image

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-touch-event

Ok so I have AppCompatActivity which is used as FragmentActivity (with viewpager etc..), and I have clickable views in this activity (header and footer).

The fragments are actually scrollable images, nothing more.
I want to split my touch events to 2 parts -  the touches at the fragments (mainly scroll), and touches on the activity views.

I thought overriding onInterceptTouchEvent inside the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

But that will disable the fragments scroll gestures, and I want to disable it only when touch occurs on the activity views.

So generally i want the activity views touches to block the fragments touch event.